# UINavigationController and UITabBarController Subclassing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

In my application I am using a subclass of the UINavigation controller and UITabBarController to override some of the orientation functions.

Is it App Store safe to use a subclass, or could my app be rejected?

Comment: You should only be rejected for using a private API.  This is a method on an object that is not documented but can be accessed though using something like `performSelector:`

Comment: Hi Eman.H, I've noticed you haven't accepted answers on any of your questions on the website. I think you should consider doing so as it's  in the spirit of the community here to have a question-solution format and reward people who take the time and help out. You can accept an answer by clicking on a check symbol next to an answer. If none of the answers are correct or help you, consider commenting on the answer to ask for more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass these. Generally you wouldn't but if you want to you can and you won't have any problems.

In fact in iOS 6 which introduced a new logic for autorotation, Apple says in their [documentation for `UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) precisely  this. It's also mentionned for [`UITabBarController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

> This class is generally used as-is but may be subclassed in iOS 6 and
>   later

Comment: That's interesting that they have changed the recommendation as of iOS 6.

Comment: Yes because these container view controllers are top level, often rootViewControllers, subclassing is one of a few solutions to make autorotation work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be rejected just for subclassing these two classes. I've done it myself in several apps.